# App config in Window Service

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a window service and it is taking input from an xml file.That file is placed in the folder of .exe itself.But i want that window service to take input from App.config.
I read that App config name gets changed to service.exe.config and every whereit is mentined how can we acces connection string from that.Can someone tell me a way to get app setting from app config in window service.

I have a googled a lot but could do that.
Current code is :

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

         current_directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            string Xml_Path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            xml.Load(current_directory + "\\Data.xml");//suppose that myXmlString contains "<Names>...</Names>"


            XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                strDir = xn["Directory"].InnerText;
                fileMask = xn["FileMask"].InnerText;
                strBatfile = xn["Batch"].InnerText;
                strlog = xn["Log"].InnerText;


            }
            //strDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory"];
            //fileMask = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileMask"];
            //strBatfile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Batch"];
            //strlog = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log"];


            m_Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();


            m_Watcher.Filter = fileMask;
            m_Watcher.Path = strDir + "\\";
            m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;




            m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);

            m_Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleated);
            m_Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);


            m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            CustomException.Write(CustomException.CreateExceptionString(exception.ToString()));
        }

    }
```

but something like.
`//strDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory"];
                //fileMask = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileMask"];
                //strBatfile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Batch"];
                //strlog = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log"];`
is not working..Also the xml is not available while release mode.
Can someone give me way to access app config to pass input param to Window service.

Comment: Can you explain why using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is not working?  It would be the usual method to use the local config file

Comment: It is just not reading from app.config.In release mode app config turns into program.exe.config and I believe thats the issue.but i am not sure,just tryng to make it work

Comment: For `ConfigurationManager` to work out of the box, the config file name needs to match the exe name with `.config` appended, as per @dotnetstep's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your window service application produces a WindowService1.exe then your configuration file App.config will get changed to WindowService1.exe.config.

Now to read from the config file you can use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]
```

If you are not able to get ConfigurationManager then you have to add a reference to the System.Configuration assembly.

Comment: So will this fix issues when editing the config file, and the windows service does not pick up the new changes? I think that's what the OP had issues with originally.